# Android 10 : /proc/net/arp: open failed: EACCES (Permission denied)

Tags: android, permissions, wifi

I'am trying to list neighbor wifi in my android application.
I'am using Android Q. I'am facing to this error :

> /proc/net/arp: open failed: EACCES (Permission denied)

This is my code :

```
br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(ARP_TABLE));
String line;
while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
    String[] splitted = line.split(" +");
    if (splitted != null && splitted.length >= 4) {
        String mac = splitted[3];
        if (mac.matches("..:..:..:..:..:..")) {
            // IP and connected
            // SOME CODE
        }
    }
}
```

Anybody is facing to this error ?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Did you try `android:requestLegacyExternalStorage` attribute in `AndroidManifest.xml`? If you didn't try this, you can use this attribute like this in Android Manifest file;

```
<manifest ... >
   <application android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true" ... >
   ...
   </application>
</manifest>
```

Comment: yes i dit that, and i still have the same error. For informations: my smartphone has updated to android version 11.

Comment: Is there another way to list neighbor wifi ?

Comment: Sure. Well, Can you add Location permission for the Wi-Fi?

Comment: It's seems that the folder "/proc/net/arp" is not accessible whatever permissions you accept. There are nothing to do. I have to find another way to list all neighbors wifi !!

Comment: @HoussamKourdache could you give us what you to do to get a neighbors wifi ?